# New jquery library is not compatible with old script

Tags: jquery, compatibility

Hi I have this piece of code:

```
$('li.dropdown-toggle').on('hover', function () {
    $(this).find(".submenu").slideToggle(200);
});
```

And I've noticed it works well under jQuery 1.7.2 library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but not under 3.1.0

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is there anything I can modify in the code above to work well under 3.1.0 ? I don't really want to change the library, just in case other scripts stop working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`hover` event with `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes) method is deprecated since jQuery version `1.8` and completely removed from jQuery version `1.9` onwards.

So now you can use [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) method to handle the event or separately use `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` event with [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method as per your need.

```
$('li.dropdown-toggle').hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".submenu").slideToggle(200);
});


// or with on 

$('li.dropdown-toggle').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).find(".submenu").slideToggle(200);
});
```